# Bevel edge problem

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

Im new in blender, im trying to make keyboard for my room render, few edges acts strangely and i cant find any solution. Any tips ? Thanks a lot :)

- [Keyboard tutorial with timestamp](https://youtu.be/6zmm3zFPubQ?t=1302)
- Problem[image: problem]Edge is red square is a problem

- Blend file download:
  [image]

Comment: Looks like it's likely the result of a duplicate or disconnected vert. Try (in edit mode) select all > mesh > clean up > merge by distance.

Comment: Already tried, no change :/ . I've attached my blend file to question . Thanks for help.

Comment: actually I can not reproduce your error. all works fine in may blender 2.83 LST version... what is your blender version?

Comment: 2.83.3. Maybe im doing something wrong but all edges except those 3 works fine  https://imgur.com/a/luaunJI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with your base topology. Specifically, in your case, three of the edges are "capped" by a whole face, but the other is right in an edge corner. Not sure why it's happening, but blender is treating them differently here. It might have something to do with the overall number of N-gons there are in that area, but I can't be sure. I'm guessing this part of the model is the result of a boolean operation, which often causes topology issues such as this.

[image: BevelFaces]

Regardless, I found the easiest way to solve it was to add two knife cuts surrounding the troublesome corner, which then allowed me to dissolve the edge bridging the two corners. I did this so the top "face cap" around the corner matches the layout of the other three. Anyway, this worked for me - see below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot with your method everything now works fine, still have no clue why only those 3 edges had problem with handling corners. BIG THANKS